# 2 Factor Authentication in SSH using public key and yubikey

Tags: sshd, pam

I'm trying to setup 2 Factor Authentication. I want to login via 2 methods:

1. Public Key > YubiKey
2. Password > YubiKey

And now I have this done, but I want to specify what users can login via password (like Match User ... PasswordAuthentication yes). If user is not in that list, he can login only via PubKey and Yubikey. How can I do that?

[This is my sshd_config](http://termbin.com/e2bs)
[This is my common-auth PAM file](http://termbin.com/6h2q)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've already known, how to do that. Just write in Match User something like this:

```
Match User OnlyPassword
    AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive:pam
```

and in default values only:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam
```